# Save file to Google Drive via "save to Drive" Button

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I am creating an Android app and want to integrate Google Drive. The aim is to save or load Files to a given Google Drive account. Is there a "save to Drive" Button for Android like for web applications which i can use.

In another App i am using a sharing intent where google drive appears with an easy dialog to save a file to drive but i want to save the file directly via a click on a Button

Thanks in Advance

Comment: gmail for android has a save to drive button but i think the button is only available in browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are meaning that you don't want to use the Drive API built in drive dialogs, you can use the createFile() function included in the Drive API.

Here is the [sample](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/create-file) taken from the android developer site:

```
public class CreateFileActivity {

    // ...

    ResultCallback<ContentsResult> contentsCallback = new
            ResultCallback<ContentsResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(ContentsResult result) {
            if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                // Handle error
                return;
            }

            MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                    .setTitle("New file")
                    .setMimeType("text/plain").build();
            // Create a file in the root folder
            Drive.DriveApi.getRootFolder(getGoogleApiClient())
                    .createFile(getGoogleApiClient(), changeSet, result.getContents())
                    .addResultCallback(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Check out their whole tutorial here: [Creating files programmatically](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/create-file#creating_files_programmatically)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have get it to work using the `CreateFileActivityBuilder` with `startIntentSenderForResult` from [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/create-file#creating_files_programmatically)

Comment: Note that as of December 2018, Google is in the process of deprecating the Android Google Drive API and forcing developers to move to the Drive REST API.